# Speeding up parallel std::vector calculations using iterator in c++

Tags: c++, performance, iterator, stdvector

I have a small function that calculates a parameter based on doing element-wise math on a list of parameters that are calculated based on the `std::vector` instances `l,t,d,n` where `l,t,d,n` are all `std::vector<double>`.  This is the pinchpoint in the speed of my program - I have profiled, and I am sure.

Here is a working snippet that uses the `[]` operator.  I am doing development in C++ in Visual C++ 2008 Express on a Core i7, 8GB RAM, Windows 7, in Release Mode with `/O2` optimization.  Ultimately this is getting compiled to a Python extension with SWIG, but let's not get ahead of ourselves.

I have also coded up a solution using C-arrays (see below)( the solution that I used to use in C, but I have gone towards an object-oriented solution in C++, which requires (for my application) the use of `std::vector`s to avoid memory leaks.)

All three solutions are below.  I have heard much talk on SO and elsewhere about how the `std::vector` iterator solution should be (always??) just as fast as the array, but my results show that 1 million calls takes the following times:

- `std::vector` with `[]` operator : 2.53 s
- `std::vector` with iterator: 2.69 s
- C-array : 0.58 s

So clearly the array solution is much faster.  Am I missing something obvious with my coding of the std::vector solutions?

### Edit

So it seems that part of my problem was in the profiling.  The optimization optimized away most of my c-array code, which is why it was so much faster than any of the std::vector options.  I think I am fundamentally limited by the throughput of doing all the exp()  and pow() calls.  Thank you everyone for all the recommendations, I think for my application I am just butting up against processor speed.  I suppose about 2 microseconds for 19*6 pow calls *isn't* really all that bad when it comes down to it.  But it is still too slow for me.  *C'est la vie...*

## `std::vector<double>` using indexing with `[]` operator

```
double phir_power::base(double tau, double delta) throw()
{
    double summer=0;
    for (unsigned int i=iStart;i<=iEnd;i++)
    {
        if (l[i]>0)
            summer+=n[i]*pow(delta,d[i])*pow(tau,t[i])*exp(-pow(delta,l[i]));
        else
            summer+=n[i]*pow(delta,d[i])*pow(tau,t[i]);
    }
    return summer;
}
```

## `std::vector<double>` with iterators

```
std::vector<double>::const_iterator n_begin=n.begin(), n_end = n.end(), n_iter = n_begin;
std::vector<double>::const_iterator d_begin=d.begin(), d_end = d.end(), d_iter = d_begin;
std::vector<double>::const_iterator t_begin=t.begin(), t_end = t.end(), t_iter = t_begin;
std::vector<double>::const_iterator l_begin=l.begin(), l_end = l.end(), l_iter = l_begin;

for (unsigned int uuu=0;uuu<1e6;uuu+=1)
{
    double summer=0;
    //Bring the iterators back to the first element
    l_iter = l_begin;
    d_iter = d_begin;
    t_iter = t_begin;
    n_iter = n_begin;
    for (; l_iter != l_end; ++l_iter,++t_iter,++d_iter,++n_iter)
    {
        if ((*l_iter)>0)
            summer+=(*n_iter)*pow(delta,(*d_iter))*pow(tau,(*t_iter))*exp(-pow(delta,(*l_iter)));
        else
            summer+=(*n_iter)*pow(delta,(*d_iter))*pow(tau,(*t_iter));
    }
    rrrrrrrr += summer;
}
t2 = clock();
printf("Time for 1 million calls  %g [s] val %g \n",((double)(t2-t1))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC,rrrrrrrr);
```

## C-array

```
double r=0;
t0 = clock();
unsigned int qwe;
double ttte = 0;
double term_;
for (unsigned int j=1;j<19;j++)
{
    t1=clock();
    r=0;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<1e6; i++)
    {
        term_ = n[j]*pow(delta,d[j])*pow(tau,t[j]);
        if (l[j]>0)
            term_ *= exp(-pow(delta,l[j]));
        r+=term_;
    }
    ttte+=r/1e6;
    t2=clock();
    printf("Index %d time %g [s] val %g\n",j,((double)(t2-t1))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC,r/1e6);
}
t3=clock();
printf("Time for 1 million calls %g [s] val is %g\n",((double)(t3-t0))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC,ttte);
```

Comment: Are your three programs identical?  If they are, it isn't obvious:  the expressions in the first two programs look more complex than those in the third.

Comment: Did you disable checked iterators? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @ÉricMalenfant This is part of a rather large code-base, and I tried disabling the checked iterator (by adding `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0;_SECURE_SCL=0` to the macro defs in project in VC2008), but the result was a crash of Visual Studio.  As I understand it, in VC2008, secure iterators are enabled in Release mode, but they are disabled in VC2010. I have also tried to add `#define _SECURE_SCL 0` to main.cpp, but that doesn't work either since you need to add `#define_SECURE_SCL 9` to every file (as I understand it).  How much difference in performance should I see?  Worth it to try again?

Comment: If you're using visual studio, you shouldn't have to manually define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING. On the visual studio toolbar, there is a dropdown. Change it from "Debug" to "Release" and you should see the iterator checking go away on its own. Choosing "Release" will also link your program with the proper library(the one without debug symbols). Finally, make sure you press Ctrl+F5 to run your program without the Debugger attached, as attaching the debugger to your app's process will slow it down a lot.

Comment: @Nick Even with Release mode and no debugging (Ctrl+F5), the c-array is still destroying the std::vector solutions.  I have read that in Visual Studio 2008, Microsoft made the decision to NOT disable iterator checking in Release mode.

Comment: WTF, your C array code is quite clearly different.

Answer (score 1):

A difference is that in the C-code you are supplying, you have a big loop inside a small loop in which nothing is changing, just doing something a million times. In the code with the iterators, you have a small loop inside a big loop, meaning it has to change the iterator all the time. This might cost extra time. I am not sure about this, but if you can test it: give it a try!

Comment: I set up my code this way for profiling purposes, it is not actually the way my code is set up in the practical application.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code based on iterators is that you need four iterators against one index i in operator[] version because you have four vectors containing one double. Maintaining four iterators is to costly. You will get better performance with the iterators using a single vector containing a struct which contains the four doubles. Actually it might be faster for the operator[] version to because of less pointer calculations and better locality of the data which should improve the throughput of your CPU.

Comment: That is an interesting idea that I hadn't thought about at all.  So I will now have something like `std::vector<values>`, where `values` is c-struct with each one of the entries?  Worth a shot.

Comment: That does work, and it is in fact faster than the multiple iterators, but it still isn't as fast as the c-array which is where I need to get.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is guaranteed to be allocated as one contiguous block of memory, so you don't have to use its `[]` operator if you don't want to.

```
double phir_power::base(double tau, double delta) throw()
{
    double summer=0;

    double *pl = &l[0];
    double *pn = &n[0];
    double *pd = &d[0];
    double *pt = &t[0];

    for (unsigned int i = iStart; i <= iEnd; i++)
    {
        if (pl[i] > 0)
            summer += pn[i] * pow(delta, pd[i]) * pow(tau, pt[i]) * exp(-pow(delta, pl[i]));
        else
            summer += pn[i] * pow(delta, pd[i]) * pow(tau, pt[i]);
    }
    return summer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the help to index the underlying data rather than the std::vector.  Sadly though there is no difference in performance.

Comment: The organization of your code also differs from the C code, and will likely generate a different assembler output, which may turn out to be slower. You could try switching back to the algorithm you used in your C code, while still using the std::vector, and accessing the data directly. Also, see my comment on your original post.

Comment: What's the purpose of circumventing operator[] when it is effectively optimized out by the compiler?